# Get SharedPreferences within another class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to access `SharedPreferences` from `LegalProsecution.java`, I ran into some errors about it not being in the same class, so I tried this in another class, `AppPreference.java`.

Here is the code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.View;

public class AppPreference
{
    private static AppPreference appprefs;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public static AppPreference getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(appprefs == null) appprefs = new AppPreference(context);
        return appprefs;
    }

    private AppPreference(Context context)
    {
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("settings",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void storeSettings(int num)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("first_run", num);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public int loadSettings()
    {
        return prefs.getInt("first_run",0);
    }
}
```

This part of the app looks good (no errors), so I got back to `LegalProsecution.java`. However, when I try to call `AppPreferences.java`, I run into issues:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

public class LegalProsecution {

    AppPreference appprefs = AppPreference.getInstance(context); // error
    if(appprefs.loadSettings == 1);
    else
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setTitle(getString(R.string.warning));
        builder1.setMessage(getString(R.string.warning_description));
        builder1.setCancelable(true);

        builder1.setPositiveButton(
                "Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.putInt("first_run",1);
                        editor.apply();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }
        );
        builder1.setNegativeButton(
                "No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
        );

        AlertDialog alert1 = builder1.create();
        alert1.show();
    }

}
```

So Android Studio complains that there is no context anymore, which is odd because I'm already in a class. Why is this?

Comment: The problem qith `if(appprefs.loadSettings == 1);` is that there's a typo. It should be: `if(appprefs.loadSettings(view) == 1);`.

Comment: A class doesn't have a context; but an activity does. I think your class misses the "extends Activity" line.

Comment: how are you getting the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of the context to the  `getInstance(context)` method.

As your `LegalProsecution` doesn't seems to have access to the context you can create your own application class with a static access to the context and then use this context everywhere.

Create your application class :

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp instance;

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return instance.getApplicationContext()
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

Add your new created application into the manifest into the existing `<application>` tag:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yourapp"
    ...
>

<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    ...
>
```

Once this done you can load your properties in your XMLParser  :

```
AppPreference appprefs = AppPreference.getInstance(MyApp.getContext());
```

Comment: Yes it's into the existing application tag. @See my updated answer : try to add just `android:name=".MyApp"`.